# Use hdfs as backend storage for kafka, is it doable?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, distributed-system

Kafka as a message pubsub system, needs to store data locally and do replication to avoid loss if crashed. My idea is to modify Kafka to let it write data directly to hdfs, so there is no need to do replication, making Kafka simpler, is it doable?

Comment: Are you planning to consume the data (with Spark, or Map-Reduce) from HDFS?

Comment: yes, that's also a plan.

Comment: If you're running Hadoop using Cloudera or Hortonworks you shouldn't have to do much as Kafka is supported by both vendors.  It should by default store data in to HDFS.

Comment: What I mean is a new tweaked design based on Kafka, no need for replication, no need for slave broker. Each broker writes append only data to HDFS and do the sub/pub work. Upon failure, master selects a new one and continues the work.

Answer (score 2):

Doable, maybe. A good idea? Almost certainly not. Kafka itself persists data and manages replication and resilience across multiple nodes for both redundancy and performance. Bringing HDFS into the mix makes no sense at all.

Comment: Why do you think its NOT a good idea? The idea behind this is that since replication can be relied upon HDFS, and kafka is basically append only. So the code can be simplified if kafka is build upon HDFS. And why do you think performance *will* be worse? need detailed explanation.

Comment: Because Kafka already does what you're talking about. Adding HDFS is the exact opposite of simplifying something. I didn't say performance would be worse. Anyway… if you want to do it, it's open-source, go ahead. I was just asking your fairly broad question with an answer and my personal opinions `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I mean because HDFS already does the replication, so if Kafka can be modified on HDFS, the Kafka code can be simpler. And from architecture level, how do you see if performance can be worse or better?

Comment: The usecase and requirements for storage in Kafka and HDFS are fundamentally different. You can read about how Kafka uses the filesystem here : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design. HDFS just doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: I know and understand what kafka does well, because I developed a similar one as kafka internally used. Why do you think HDFS doesn't make sense here?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use replication, in the case a broker failing u wont be able to get the data to be sent to the partition and you won't be able to receive any data from that point on.
Replication isn't just for saving data when a broker crashes, it also ensures robustness of the system.

Comment: Nope, no replication, but there IS primary and slave broker, so upon detecting primary broker down, a slave will serve the publish/subscribe request, it will read/write the data from the underlying HDFS storage.

Comment: If the slave broker takes up the work then it must have a In-sync replication of the topic partition in order to continue. Also reading and writing from hdfs wont give you the speed of kafka keep that in mind.

Comment: The slave broker just monitors the primary (e.g. primary register itself from zookeeper, etc), if primary is down, slave will load the topic data from the HDFS, so there is no need for replication.

Comment: I dont know what broker you are using. There is no such broker which executes user defined code and loads from hdfs. And you are forgetting the speed of data copy from hdfs which is slow itself.

Comment: I mean I'll modify the kafka source code to do it in that way, any possible concerns?

Comment: I find there is NO need for a slave broker, a master node will monitor the brokers and select one for failover, so the design consists of: 1 master, N brokers (no primary or slave). Broker writes append only data to HDFS, and upon failure, master detects and selects a new broker.